# PDO Exception when DESCRIBE table

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am getting the error:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near "mytable"  at
>   line 1

When I call the below function using

```
$fields = Table::getFieldsForTable('mytable');
```

If I hard-code `:t` to my table name, then the code executes fine.

```
 public static function getFieldsForTable ($table ) {
            $sql = 'DESCRIBE :t';

            try {
                /**
                 * @var $db \PDO
                 */
                $db = static::getDB();
                $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);

                $stmt->bindValue(':t', $table, PDO::PARAM_STR);

                $stmt->execute();

                return $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            } catch (\PDOException $e){
                echo "PDO ERROR" . $e->getMessage();
            }
        }
```

I have used the same code snippet over and over in other parts of the project, but I am failing to see what I have done wrong here.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply because table or column names cannot be replaced by parameters in PDO - it's just a fundamental restriction in the way it works.

See answers to duplicate question:
[Can PHP PDO Statements accept the table or column name as parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182287/can-php-pdo-statements-accept-the-table-or-column-name-as-parameter)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15990488/180733
is an excellent explanation.

If you are concerned about the security of accepting an arbitrary table name, consider an up-front fetch of all table names using `SHOW TABLES`, and then validate the proposed table name against that list, using `in_array ($table, $tables)`.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know that. I'll just add just my $sql line to compensate.

Answer (score 0):

`bindValue` with `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` quotes the string as if it's a value you'd use for insert or select etc. Just concat the string

```
$sql="DESCRIBE ".$table;.
```

For security develop a regex that detects only valid table names, e.g. something like this

```
preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z]{1}[a-zA-Z_]{1,18}$/',$table);
```

Or match against a whitelist, e.g. array of accepted tables